# Showing video and images

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have my video and images stored in the NSData format in a cache.I want to retrieve the image and show it on imageController also want to retrieve video and and show it on videoController.
I can distinguish them by looking towards the file extension. But the problem is in imageController i can init image by using the NSData:

```
        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO]];
        UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
```

But how can i use the NSData to play the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get their path extensions, you can just use separate implementations for each type.  No need to have one way down the road, eh?

```
-(void)example:(NSString*)filePath {
    if ([filePath.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO]];
        UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
    } else if ([filePath.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"mp4"]) {
        MPMoviePlayerController *player =
        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: [NSURL urlWithString:filePath]];
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
        [myView addSubview: player.view];
        // ...
        [player play];
    }
}
```

Comment: @codiFi:its fine.But if i go with this way.I have to first download the complete video and then play it from the local disk.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need a video stream, which MPMoviePlayer has built-in.  This was merely an example

Comment: but how can i store the video into the cache?

Comment: Don't you mean "mp4" not "m4p"?